# How to vary node inputs based on the fields of *specific* geometry?

Tags: geometry-nodes

First, I created my own `arcMesh` node group. It does the nearly the same as the builtin curve primitive `Arc`.
[image: arcMesh node group]

`arcMesh` was used in another node group `ringMesh`, which turns an arc into a ring by extrusion and scaling given parameters:
[image: ringMesh node group]

Now I created multiple instances of `ringMesh` along a line:
[image: top level node setup]

This is what I see if I remove the connection above the green arrow. The `Inner Radius` of all instances is uniform. Just like the then constant input to `ringMesh`.
[image]

Now I want to vary the `Inner Radius` depending on the z-Coordinate of the vertices that instance the `ringMesh`es (by restoring the connection above the green arrow):
[image: spirals???]

### Why is this happening?

It looks like as if the field resolution went wrong. **Within** each instance of `arcMesh`, input `Radius` should stay the same. Only `Inner Radius` should vary over the instances of `ringMesh`.
Instead, as you can see, `Radius` varies within each `arcMesh`... Leaving me with spirals... What can I do to get `ringMesh`es of varying (internally constant!) `InnerRadius`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you feed the Z position into the ringMesh node, this is not actually the position of the instance, but the position of each individual vertex of the ring. The inputs of the ringMesh group are evaluated before the instances are created, and then each instance has the same shape.

The Z position is used in 2 places:

1. The original mesh line Z position that determines the angle now also comes in sneakily via the "Radius" input, which means the radius gets larger for each vertex and you get this spiral shape.
2. In the ringMesh group the Inner Radius input is also the Z position in fact, but now the vertices have already been placed and Z is 0. Dividing by 0 returns 0 (because the nodes always make nice values), you add 1, and scale by that - so this has no effect at all.

Instances will not let you make 3 rings with different internal radii. Instead you need to copy the node group itself 3 times and give it 3 different radius inputs, then join the geometry outputs.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation. To be honest, it's a bit of a bummer that copy/pasting is currently needed for this use-case..

Comment: Agreed, i hope there will be support for parallel loops/arrays soon ("do X for each point in this mesh" sort of thing). I often make a large base grid, cut it into pieces, and then deform each part based on a sub-index. But that gets quite complicated and requires juggling a lot of indices.